# Pairing two android bluetooth devices without any passkey popup

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to pair two android bluetooth devices (Kitkat) without any popup for passkey exchange. I tried setpin() and cancelPairingUserInput()  methods  inside the broadcast receiver for PAIRING_REQUEST intent using reflection, but got no results. Can anyone help me with that ?

```
 if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)){

               BluetoothDevice localBluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE");
               try {

                   Log.d("setPin()", "Try to set the PIN");
                   Method m = localBluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
                   m.invoke(localBluetoothDevice, ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(1234).array());
                   Log.d("setPin()", "Success to add the PIN.");
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("setPin()", e.getMessage());
                 }
               Class localClass = localBluetoothDevice.getClass();
               Class[] arrayOfClass = new Class[0];
               try {
                   localClass.getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(localBluetoothDevice, true);
                localClass.getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", arrayOfClass).invoke(localBluetoothDevice, null);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
```

Comment: Add some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Ali: added code snippet

Comment: no answer from anyone..  :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling createBond() through reflection?

This works for me, with device being a BluetoothDevice:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the device and the PIN (or the pairing key) from the given Intent
2. if the given PIN is not -1, set it in the device
3. invoke the device's .setPairingConfirmation() method

My code (which achieves this) in the .bluetoothEventReceived() callback method, looks something like this:

```
private void bluetoothEventRecieved(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        int pin = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY, -1);
        if (pin != -1) {
            byte[] pinBytes = String.format(Locale.US, "%04d", pin).getBytes();
            device.setPin(pinBytes);
        }
        device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
    }
}
```